# How do I use an external module's types in TypeScript definition file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I am trying to reference Mongoose types in a TypeScript definition file. Currently I'm using a regular `.ts` file so that I can just do

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

but I want it to be a proper definition file (`.d.ts`). Problem is that `import`s are not allowed in definition files. So I've tried this

```
/// <reference types="mongoose" />
interface doc extends mongoose {}
interface doc extends mongoose.Document {}
```

and

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts" />
interface doc extends mongoose { }
interface doc extends mongoose.Document {}
```

but neither of them work - regardless of whether I use `mongoose` or `Mongoose`. VS Code just says `cannot find name 'mongoose'` or `cannot find namespace 'mongoose'`.

I'm at a loss here. How can I use definitions from an external module in my definition file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the mongoose typings have a default export, which may be causing this issue. Try adding `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'` or `import mongoose = require('mongoose')` in your d.ts file

Comment: See my question, imports aren't allowed in definition files.

Comment: I believe they are. Look at some of the external angular d.ts files for example: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular-breadcrumb/index.d.ts